# Debugging library functions with Xdebug

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I am using PhpStorm + XAMPP+ xdebug for WordPress project. I want to step into function `language_attributes()` definition while debugging like we do in .net or in Android Studio.

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
```

[image]

On console it is giving me the error :

> Call to undefined function bloginfo() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\Twitter-BootstrapBlankTheme\header.php
>   on line 12

I took up `xampp` as root to include every built-in library.

I am not finding any relevant post related to this. Please suggest.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to debug. Looks more like you want autocompletion and/or show function signatures of wordpress' functions (this has nothing to do with debugging).

Comment: As far as xdebug is concerned, it's just more code so if you set a breakpoint there or in the method itself, you should be able to step through it without any problems. What is the exact problem?

Comment: That's not a built-in php function. WordPress probably.

Comment: 1) *"I took up xampp as root to include every built-in library."* You do not need to do that -- having `wordpress` as project root is enough as WordPress installation is self-sufficient. 2) So far it looks like you have executed (trying to debug) wrong file so some of the WP functionality was simply not loaded. You need to run/debug main WordPress file (`index.php`) which will load all necessary files and then it will step into your `header.php` of your custom theme.

Comment: 3) I suggest checking this official link: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/WordPress+Development+using+PhpStorm

Comment: i did work on index.php , nothing happened